# Batch: Set one directory up path in variable

Tags: batch-file

Hi i am mapping a shell script code to batch script so i came across  a statement in shell script like this

> ```
> BASEDIR=`cd ../;pwd`
> ```

But have no idea how to do that. I know that %CD% will give me current directory but i want to set one directory up path in variable . Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit more complex as in shell code.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A in ("%CD%\..") do set "basedir=%%~fA"
```

**Edit related to your comment:**

To replace `\` with `\\` just add the line

```
set "basedir=%basedir:\=\\%"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ("%cd%") do set "upper_dir=%%~dpa"
```

Comment: You are a second faster

Answer (score 2):

Another way...

```
pushd ..
set "BaseDir=%CD%"
popd
```

Comment: But you should surround it with quotes `set "BaseDir=%CD%"` so it can also works with `C:\programs & Docs\mySubDir\`

Comment: Sir i have one more query now in that file there is "exit ret" where ret is a variable i have also declared same variable now how to exit and return from batch file.

Comment: i want to replace also \ with \\ in that sorry to write that...so that path would look like c:\\program\\..

Comment: Something such as EXIT %ret% where ret is your variable name. See EXIT /?

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
@echo off
set "dir=C:\Windows\System32"
call:up %dir%
:up
echo/%~dp1
```

Comment: It executes the echo two times, you forgot the `exit /b` after the `call`. You get problems with some directory names like `C:\Amp & Caret^\mySubdir`