# Batch : How to get absolute path from batch script

Tags: shell, batch-file

I am converting a shell script file to batch file.  i have done

```
> D:\project\fault-collector\build\mods\com.project~FCA~0.0.1\bin>echo %cd%
```

And i got like this

> D:\project\fault-collector\build\mods\com.project~FCA~0.0.1\bin

but i want it to be like this with one directory up without bin directory.

```
D:\\project\\fault-collector\\build\\mods\\com.project~FCA~0.0.1
```

with "\\" but i have no idea how to do that ... I am doing batch scripting first time in my life. please help.

Comment: `D:\\Fixstream\\netra-fault-collector\\build\\mods\\com.fixstream~FCA~0.0.1` - this should be the final result or you want to clear double slashes?

Comment: yes ....i want this as final result the path is result of %cd% but it has single "\" only i want it printed with  "\\". please answer i have never done batch scripting before...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch: Set one directory up path in variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943087/batch-set-one-directory-up-path-in-variable)

Comment: @Mofi no ...by that i got one directory up but now i want single "\" to be printed like "\\" ...

Comment: Ok guys i found it by some editing answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943087/batch-set-one-directory-up-path-in-variable

Comment: Hi so i found my answer by editing in post 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943087/batch-set-one-directory-up-path-in-variable][1]
just need to so 
set BASEDIR=%cd:\=\\%
and it will make address with all "\\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ("%cd%") do set "upper_dir=%%~pa" & set "drv=%%~da"
set "upper_dir=%upper_dir:\=\\%"
set final_path=%drv%%upper_dir%
```